# Instantiating class in loop in javascript uses last value

Tags: javascript, class, loops, closures

First of all, I'm aware there are many questions about closures in JavaScript, especially when it comes to loops. I've read through many of them, but I just can't seem to figure out how to fix my own particular problem. My main experience lies with C#, C++ and some ASM and it is taking some getting used to JavaScript.

I'm trying to populate a 3-dimensional array with new instances of a class (called Tile) in some for loops. All I want to do is pass along a reference to some other class (called Group) that gets instantiated in the first loop (and also added to another array). As you might have guessed, after the loops are done, every instance of the Tile class has a reference to the same Group object, namely the last one to be created.

Apparently instead of passing a reference to the Group object, a reference to some variable local to the function is passed along, which is updated in every iteration of the loop. My assumption is that solving this problem has something to do with closures as this appears to be the case with many similar problems I've come across while looking for a solution.

I've posted some trimmed down code that exposes the core of the problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eZMtQ/2/):

```
//GW2 namespace
(function( GW2, $, undefined ) {

    //GW2Tile class
    GW2.Tile = function(globalSettings, kineticGroup)
    {
        //Private vars
        var tilegroup = kineticGroup;
//      console.log(tilegroup.grrr); //Shows the correct value
        var settings = globalSettings;

        this.Test = function(){
            console.log(tilegroup.grrr);
        }

        this.Test2 = function(group){
            console.log(group.grrr);
        }

    } //Class

}( window.GW2 = window.GW2 || {}, jQuery ));


var zoomGroups = [];
var tiles = [];
var settings = {};

InitArrays();
tiles[0,0,0].Test(); //What I want to work, should give 0
tiles[0,0,0].Test2(zoomGroups[0]); //How I'd work around the issue

function InitArrays(){
    var i, j, k, zoomMultiplier, tile;

    for(i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
        zoomGroups[i] = {};
        zoomGroups[i].grrr = i;

        tiles[i] = [];
        zoomMultiplier = Math.pow(2, i);
        for(j = 0; j < zoomMultiplier; j++){
            tiles[i,j] = [];
            for(k = 0; k < zoomMultiplier; k++){
                tile = new GW2.Tile(settings, zoomGroups[i]);
                tiles[i,j,k] = tile;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Up till now when working with JavaScript, I've generally fiddled with the code a bit to make it work, but I'm tired of using work-arounds that look messy as I know there should actually be some fairly simple solution. I'm just not fond of asking for help, but this is really doing my head in. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve with `tiles[0,0,0]`? -- this construction wont be doing what you expect I think... not in JavaScript.

Comment: The first thing that catch my eye is "syntax" like `tiles[0,0,0]` - I guess what you mean is `tiles[0][0][0]`. `[0,0,0]` itself _construct an array_.

Comment: use `tiles[i]`, `tiles[i][j]` and `tiles[i][j][k]`

Comment: I'm guessing the notation I used actually being valid code for something else caused no errors to be raised. *crawls into a corner and sobs*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Multidimensional arrays

#### The problem

The first issue with your code above is how you are attempting to create multidimensional arrays.

The syntax you are using is:

```
tiles[0,0,0]
```

However, the way JavaScript will interpret this is:

```
tiles[0]
```

#### Accessing a multidim array

If you wish to access a multidim array you have to use:

```
tiles[0][0][0]
```

And to create a multidim array you would need to do the following:

```
tiles = [];
tiles[0] = [];
tiles[0][0] = [];
tiles[0][0][0] = 'value';
```

or:

```
tiles = [[['value']]];
```

### With respect to your code

In your code you should be using:

```
tiles[i][j][k] = tile;
```

But you should also make sure that each sub array actually exists before setting it's value, otherwise you'll get `undefined` or `illegal offset` errors.

You can do this by way of:

```
(typeof tiles[i] === 'undefined') && (tiles[i] = []);
(typeof tiles[i][j] === 'undefined') && (tiles[i][j] = []);
tiles[i][j][k] = tile;
```

Obviously the above can be optimised depending on how you are traversing your loops i.e. it would be best to make sure the `tiles[i]` level exists as an array before stepping in to the the `[j]` loop, and then not worry about checking it's existence again whilst stepping `j`.

### Other options

Depending on what your dataset is, or at least what you hope to do with the `tiles` array it can be worth considering using an object instead:

```
/// set up
tiles = {};

/// assignment
tiles[i+','+j+','+k] = 'value';
```

However this method is likely to be slower, although I've been proved wrong a number of times by my assumptions and differing JavaScript interpreters. This would probably be were [jsPerf](http://www.jsperf.com) would be your friend.

### Optimisation

One benefit of using the `tiles[i][j][k]` approach is that it gives you the chance to optimise your references. For example, if you were about to process a number of actions at one level of your multidimensional array, you should do this:

```
/// set up
var ij = tiles[i][j];

/// use in loops or elsewhere
ij[k] = 'value'
```

This is only of benefit if you were to access the same level more than once however.

Comment: Ooph, that certainly made me feel stupid. Thanks for the answer! It's always whatever you're not looking at of course :)

Comment: @Sizzling no worries -- easy to make mistakes when translating over from other languages :) have to say that [0,0,0] syntax utterly confused me for a while.. heh, anyway hope it helped.